# Is $\frac{dx(t-T)}{d(t-T)}=\frac{dx(t-T)}{dt}$? Where T is a constant and t is an independent variable.

Tags: derivatives

Given a function x(t) and a constant T, is the following relation true?:
$$\frac{dx(t-T)}{d(t-T)}=\frac{dx(t-T)}{dt}$$

If it is true, what is the proof?

Also, if this is true, does this mean that this statement is wrong?:
$$\frac{dx(t-T)}{d(t-T)}=\frac{dx(z)}{dz}=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$$ where $z=t-T$.

Here is a snippet from Example 1.11 of Linear Systems and Signals by B. P. Lathi and Roger Green using this relation:

> Applying input $x(t)$ to the system produces output $y(t) = \frac{d}{dt}x(t)$; delaying
> this output by T produces $y(t − T) = \frac{d}{d(t−T)}x(t − T) = \frac{d}{dt}x(t − T)$. This is just the output of
> the system to a delayed input $x(t−T)$. Since the T-delayed output of the system to input $x(t)$
> equals the output of the system to the T-delayed input $x(t−T)$, the system is time invariant.

This part refers to proving the system $y(t)=\frac{d}{dt}x(t)$ to be time invariant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is the chain rule, using $$\frac{d(t-T)}{dt} = 1\qquad\text{or its consequence}\qquad \frac{dt}{d(t-T)} = 1$$

---

Yes,
$$
\frac{dx(z)}{dz}=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}
$$
is wrong, where $z=t-T$.  Unless $x(t)$ is periodic with period $T$, then it is right.

Comment: Ouch! can't believe I missed that. Thank you.